# Is it offtopic to play or anounce games through BCG?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, chat

For now it probably is, but I can imagine the following in the future (if there is a chat channel available):

- Werewolf chat, I have a lot of good experiences with this. The games are mostly fast and fun.
- Diplomacy, diplomacy phase by chat and email, current maps are shown possible trough the site or a dedicated other site.

In both cases I volunteer to lead the games, I have enough experience with both.

And there are lots of other games that can be played through a channel. (I have some plans to adapt Advanced Civilization for pbem. But I need to work out the trade phase).

Comment: Upvoted because this is a good question, not because I agree that the site should be used for these purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through chat, I don't think it's off topic. That's what the chat rooms are for; any sort of off topic, idle conversation, or stuff that isn't relevant to or doesn't work well in a question and answer format.

Of course, not all that many people seem to actually use the chat functionality on the Trilogy/StackExchange sites; only the Tavern has any real significant use, as far as I've seen. Also, there are no private message facilities, so we'd have to use something out of band for that. Given these issues, chat might not be the best forum for these sorts of games; there are lots of other forums in which you can play them already.

It wouldn't work well on the main site or meta. Even announcing games or asking for people interested in them on the main site should be discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be off topic. However, if there is a site where people can announce games, or even a twitter tag, then I would expect to see a question such as "Where can I find announcements for online game sessions" etc.